# dexexception: not support version

Tags: apk, dex, android-8.0-oreo, decompiler

I was trying to convert apk to source code. When I entered below command

```
./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

I got this exception:

```
com.googlecode.d2j.DexException: not support version.
at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:151)
at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:211)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java:104)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:288)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:32)
```

Version of my apk is Oreo and dexcompiler is dex2jar-2.0.
 As much as I Know this dexcompiler supports upto N version (correct me if I am wrong). I have searched about this exception, but I didn't find any answers.

Please help me to resolve this exception

Comment: Try filing an issue with dex2jar? It sounds like it just needs to be updated.

Comment: The author is not active any more. there are 11 pull request to merge and 375 issues.

Answer (score 51):

I had the same problem. Used the updated version. Now it works fine.

https://github.com/DexPatcher/dex2jar/releases/download/v2.1-20171001-lanchon/dex-tools-2.1-20171001-lanchon.zip

Comment: Link is outdated, releases can be found at https://github.com/DexPatcher/dex2jar/releases

Comment: Thank you @nijave, i would recomend anyone to always search for the latest to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2):

(2021) get the dex2jar-2.1.zip from this link https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases
first enter this command  d2j-dex2jar -h
then run the second command  d2j-dex2jar "yourapkfile" .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I me the same problem.

Use the link from @john will work under android 8.

However my device is android 10 ( this is quit common ) .

In my experience, just change the header content of dex file (039 -> 036 or other supported version) sometimes ok, sometimes failed. it depends your apk uses new Java grammar or so.